# Export Wizard SQL Server Management Studio cannot locate mapping file cannot convert data types to fit Postgresql

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, ssis, ssis-2008, file-mapping

I want to export databases from our `SQL Server 2008` to our `PostgreSQL server`.

The problem is that during the `Import/Export Wizard` the `Wizard` says that he cannot find the correct file to convert properly. (If I proceed he exports without checking which leads to wrong conversion -> data won't export, only table definitions)

I believe the solution is to make the requested file - but I don't know how. It is two of those `XML-files` you find in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\MappingFiles
```

I have found some information on these websites, but I can't put the info together to make sense out of it:

- [how to add a new mapping file](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/dfce5ec6-c862-416f-b06d-eb6078e9958b/how-to-add-a-new-mapping-file?forum=sqlintegrationservices)
- [SSIS 2008 Import Export Wizard can show numbers instead of data type](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2152728/ssis-2008-import-export-wizard-can-show-numbers-instead-of-data-type)
- [Trying to add ODBC to SSIS11 XML Mapping file in SSMS](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7c08d3bc-67b7-43ae-a8e6-cb7d3c393d72/trying-to-add-odbc-to-ssis11-xml-mapping-file-in-ssms?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

I'm working with SQL Server Studio Management 2017, Export via .Net Framework Data Provide for Odbc. My Plan are files alá MSSql10ToODBC.XML and SSIS10ToODBC.XML

Has anyone ever done this or any ideas what I can do?

Comment: did you find the solution?